# Handling data quality issues on medium csv report. Best Practices

Tags: c#, design-patterns, azure-functions

#### Need help with a **better pratices** question

I have an **azure function** that brings data form differents APIs and match them toguether to create a final csv report. I have a poblation of 60k-100k and 30 columns

For the sake of the explanation, I'm going to use a small School example.

```cs
public Student {
    string Grade {get; set;}
    Name   LegName {get; set;}
    string FatherName {get; set;}
    string TeacherId {get; set;}
    string SchoolId {get; set;}
}

public Name {
    string FirstName {get; set;}
    string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Before constructing the report, I create two `Dictionary` with <Id, Name> from two APIs that expose Schools and Teachers information. And of course, a list of `Student` that comes from the Student APIs. I have no control of this trhee APIs, design, data quality, nothing.

Now, when I have all the data, I start to create the report.

```cs
string GenerateTXT(Dictionary<string, string> schools, Dictionary<string,  string> teachers, Student students){
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var student in students){
        content.Append($"{student.Grade}\t");
        content.Append($"{student.LegName.FirstName}\t");
        content.Append($"{student.LegName.LastName}\t");
        content.Append($"{schools.TryGetValue(student.TeacherId)}\t");
        content.Append($"{teachers.TryGetValue(student.SchoolId)}t";        
        content.Append($"{student.FatherNme}\t");
        content.AppendLine();
    }

    return content.ToString();    
}
```

Now here comes the problem. I started noticing data quality issues so the function started throwing exceptions. For example, students who do not have a valid school or teacher, or a student who does not have a name. I tried to solve expected scenarios and exception handling.

```cs
string GenerateTXT(Dictionary<string, string> schools, Dictionary<string,  string> teachers, Student students){
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    var value = string.Empty;
    foreach(var student in students){
        try {
            content.Append($"{student.Grade}\t");
            content.Append($"{student.LegName.FirstName}\t");
            content.Append($"{student.LegName.LastName}\t");            
            if(teachers.TryGetValue(student.TeacherId))
                content.Append($"{teachers[student.TeacherId]}\t");
            else
                content.Append($"\t");
            if(schools.TryGetValue(student.SchoolId))
                content.Append($"{schools[student.SchoolId]}\t");
            else
                content.Append($"\t");            
            content.Append($"{student.FatherNme}\t");
            content.AppendLine();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            log.Error($"Error reading worker {student.FirstName}");
        }
        
    }
    return content.ToString();
}
```

The problem with this is that when an unexpected error happens, I **stop** reading the next columns of data that maybe I have and instead jump to the next worker. Therefore, if a student for some random reason does not have a name, that row in the report will only have the grade, and nothing else, but I actually had the rest of the values. So here comes the question. I could put a `try catch` on each column, but remember that my real scenario has like 30 columns and could be more... so I think it's a really bad solution. Is there a pattern to solve this in a better way?

### Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first bit of advice I am going to give you is to use [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). This is a tried and true library as it handles all those edge cases you will never think of. So, saying that, give this a shot:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public Name LegName { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolId { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class NormalizedData
{
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Teacher { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
}

static void GenerateCSVData(CsvHelper.CsvWriter csv, Dictionary<string, string> schools,
    Dictionary<string, string> teachers, Student[] students)
{
    var normalizedData = students.Select(x => new NormalizedData
    {
        Grade = x.Grade,
        FatherName = x.FatherName,
        FirstName = x.LegName?.FirstName, // sanity check incase LegName is null
        LastName = x.LegName?.LastName, // ...
        School = schools.ContainsKey(x.SchoolId ?? string.Empty) ? schools[x.SchoolId] : null,
        Teacher = teachers.ContainsKey(x.TeacherId ?? string.Empty) ? teachers[x.TeacherId] : null
    });
    csv.WriteRecords(normalizedData);
}

private static string GenerateStringCSVData(Dictionary<string, string> schools,
    Dictionary<string, string> teachers, Student[] students)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using(var sr = new StreamWriter(ms, leaveOpen: true))
        using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sr,
            new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            Delimiter = ",", // change this to "\t" if you want to use tabs
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        }))
        {
            GenerateCSVData(csv, schools, teachers, students);
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
    }
}

private static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var teachers = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "j123", "Jimmy Carter" },
        { "r334", "Ronald Reagan" },
        { "g477", "George Bush" }
    };
    var schools = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "s123", "Jimmy Carter University" },
        { "s334", "Ronald Reagan University" },
        { "s477", "George Bush University" }
    };

    var students = new Student[]
    {
        new Student
        {
            FatherName = "Bob Jimmy",
            SchoolId = "s477",
            Grade = "5",
            LegName = new Name{ FirstName = "Apple", LastName = "Jimmy" },
            TeacherId = "r334"
        },
        new Student
        {
            FatherName = "Jim Bobby",
            SchoolId = null, // intentional
            Grade = "", // intentional
            LegName = null, // intentional
            TeacherId = "invalid id" // intentional
        },
        new Student
        {
            FatherName = "Mike Michael",
            SchoolId = "s123",
            Grade = "12",
            LegName = new Name{ FirstName = "Peach", LastName = "Michael" },
            TeacherId = "g477"
        },
    };

    var stringData = GenerateStringCSVData(schools, teachers, students);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Grade,FirstName,LastName,School,Teacher,FatherName
5,Apple,Jimmy,George Bush University,Ronald Reagan,Bob Jimmy
,,,,,Jim Bobby
12,Peach,Michael,Jimmy Carter University,George Bush,Mike Michael
```

So, you can see, one of the students has invalid data in it, but it recovers just fine by placing blank data instead of crashing or throwing exceptions.

Now I haven't seen your original data, so there may be more tweaks you have to make to this to cover all edge cases, but it will be a lot easier to tweak this when using CsvHelper as your writer.

Comment: Thanks for the time! So, broadly speaking, your recommendation is to handle every possible scenario in every column until an exception is not possible. Nice tip on CsvHelper

Comment: @Aferrercrafter -- yes, you want to process all the data without stopping. You already know that data could be/is missing, but that's OK if that's the case. You could, instead of setting blank data, put "<NOT AVAILABLE>" in those spots so whoever is consuming this CSV knows it was intentional because the data wasn't there in your original set.

Comment: Yes, blank spaces are a business rule. Also the order of the columns, my problem started because several of the last columns were hacoded values. So for every error that I slipped into handling it, I had hundreds of rows with empty columns, including columns ​​that should always be there, because are harcoded values